# DateTime.Now with millisecond precision trimmed the last digit

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a code to get server timestamp with millisecond precision (3 digits) along with timezone info:

```
var localTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

It has been working so fine, but just one time I see in the logs that the last digit of the millisecond has been trimmed and it shows only till the two digits:

```
2023-11-13T13:40:54.02+11:00
```

I tried to find the root cause thinking that this happens when last digit of the millisecond is 0. So, I wrote this code to debug it:

```
var testTime = DateTime.Today.AddMilliseconds(20).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

But it works just fine and I see this as a result:

```
2023-11-20T00:00:00.020+11:00
```

Any idea what could have caused what I see in the logs?

Comment: The `decimal` type remembers how many digits there are, but `DateTime` does not. Sounds like your logging code is using a different string format.